# How to extract class names from a CSS selector?

Tags: javascript, css, parsing, css-selectors, eslint

**The Story:**

I'm currently building a ESLint rule to warn about using bootstrap layout-oriented and angular technical classes inside CSS selector locators. Currently I'm using a simple substring in a string approach:

```
for (var i = 0; i < prohibitedClasses.length; i++) {
  if (node.arguments[0].value.indexOf(prohibitedClasses[i]) >= 0) {
    context.report({
      node: node,
      message: 'Unexpected Bootstrap class "' + prohibitedClasses[i] + '" inside a CSS selector'
    })
  }
```

But it has not proved to be reliable. For example, it throws an error 2 times on `.col-sm-offset-11` CSS selector reporting both `col-sm-offset-1` and `col-sm-offset-11` to be used. I can imagine it can easily break on more complex selectors with multiple pseudo-classes used.

---

**The Question:**

What is the *most reliable* way to extract class names from a CSS selector?

---

Here is a sample test list we should cover (to be improved):

```
.col-sm-push-4                 // -> ['col-sm-push-4']
.myclass.col-lg-pull-8         // -> ['myclass', 'col-lg-pull-8']
[class*='col-md-offset-4']     // -> []
[class$=col-md-offset-11]      // -> []
[class~="col-md-10"] .myclass  // -> ['col-md-10', 'myclass']
.col-md-10,.col-md-11          // -> ['col-md-10', 'col-md-11']
```

Note that we need to skip the `^=`, `$=` and `*=` partial class filter values leaving the `~=` (thanks for the comments).

Comment: I agree with @adeneo. It's an interesting question, but *"use this library"* isn't much of an answer. It doesn't directly address the question of "how".

Comment: @squint good point. I'm completely open to answers addressing the "how". Just wanted to share the interesting problem and the way I've approached it. Thanks!

Comment: It's not reliable to extract class names from *= and $= attribute selectors unless you assume they will never match elements with class names that happen to contain those substrings but are not equal to them.

Comment: @BoltClock ah, I should take into the account the "strictly equal" only. Let me see if I should update the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Note that ~= on the other hand is reliable - in HTML, it is equivalent to a class selector.

Comment: While I think the question is a little too broad, one approach would be to build a minimal parser. Seems like this would be easy enough if you simply consume the selector until you reach a `.` or a `[`, at which point you actually parse the values until their closing, which isn't too complex, and then repeat the process. I guess you'd also have to make sure they're not in a `:not()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specially designed for the problem package called [`node-css-selector-parser`](https://github.com/mdevils/node-css-selector-parser) which lacks the "how to use it" part to extract the class names. Filling the gap, here is how I've applied it to the problem.

With `node-css-selector-parser`, we can parse a CSS selector and based on a result type analyze class names used with a dot (e.g. `.myclass`) and class names used inside the attribute selector (e.g. `[class*=test]`):

```
// setup up CSS selector parser
var CssSelectorParser = require('css-selector-parser').CssSelectorParser
var parser = new CssSelectorParser()

parser.registerSelectorPseudos('has', 'contains')
parser.registerNestingOperators('>', '+', '~')
parser.registerAttrEqualityMods('^', '$', '*', '~')
parser.enableSubstitutes()

function extractClassNames (rule) {
  var classNames = []
  // extract class names defined with ".", e.g. .myclass
  if (rule.classNames) {
    classNames.push.apply(classNames, rule.classNames)
  }

  // extract class names defined in attributes, e.g. [class*=myclass]
  if (rule.attrs) {
    rule.attrs.forEach(function (attr) {
      if (attr.name === 'class') {
        classNames.push(attr.value)
      }
    })
  }

  return classNames
}

module.exports = function (cssSelector) {
  try {
    var result = parser.parse(cssSelector)
  } catch (err) {
    // ignore parsing errors - we don't want it to fail miserably on a target machine during a ESLint run
    console.log('Parsing CSS selector: "' + cssSelector + '". ' + err)
    return []
  }

  // handling empty inputs
  if (!result) {
    return []
  }

  var classNames = []

  if (result.type === 'ruleSet') {
    var rule = result.rule
    while (rule) {
      classNames.push.apply(classNames, extractClassNames(rule))
      rule = rule.rule
    }
  } else if (result.type === 'selectors' && result.selectors) {
    result.selectors.forEach(function (selector) {
      var srule = selector.rule
      while (srule) {
        classNames.push.apply(classNames, extractClassNames(srule))
        srule = srule.rule;
      }
    })
  }
  return classNames
}
```

([`standard`](https://github.com/feross/standard) code style is used - hence, for instance, no `;` at the end of the lines)

This proved to work for me and hopefully would help others with a similar problem. Note that in this state this code would also extract the partial class values passed into the `^=`, `$=` and `*=` which ideally need to be skipped.